# Fit Subview inside UIWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` (`loadWeb`) with width, height dependent on the screen size.

It's basically a box in the centre of the screen though.

Now I have added a `gif` image to this web view like this:

```
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("loading34", ofType: "gif")
    var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
    loadWeb.loadData(gif, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
```

The problem is, depending on the gif size it ends up not fitting properly inside the `UIWebView`

Is there a way of saying something like

```
gif.width = loadWeb.width
gif.height = loadWeb.height
```

or something with the same results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the scalesPageToFit property on the UIWebView.  Set it to yes and see what the behavior is, in many cases it is able to zoom out so the width of the content fits within the webViews bounds.